# Error while removing file (Function not implemented)

Tags: arch-linux, mount, rm

I get the following error trying to remove a file:

```
$ rm 22621.525.220925-0207.ni_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_x64FRE_en-us.iso                                                                              1 ✘ 
rm: cannot remove '22621.525.220925-0207.ni_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_x64FRE_en-us.iso': Function not implemented
```

Using the command `mount`:

```
$ mount
... (not interesting)
httpdirfs on /home/matrix/.cache/pikaur/build/ttf-ms-win11-auto/src/mnt/http type fuse.httpdirfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

By the way, `22621.525.220925-0207.ni_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_x64FRE_en-us.iso` is inside `/home/matrix/.cache/pikaur/build/ttf-ms-win11-auto/src/mnt/http`.

What command should I use to fix this?

Comment: You are trying to delete a file from (presumably) Microsoft's web server. How do you *expect* it to work?

Answer (score 10):

If you no longer want to see the file locally, you need to either:

- unmount the HTTPDirFS file system:

  ```
  umount /home/matrix/.cache/pikaur/build/ttf-ms-win11-auto/src/mnt/http
  ```
- delete the file on the HTTP server you’re accessing through HTTPDirFS.